# Sending a series of questions using my slack bot

Tags: slack-api

I have a slack bot that I am building for slack.
In my test workspace, the bot is installed and I can send messages as the bot to any user.  If a user reply to the bot nothing happens at the moment.

I want to understand what I need to setup in the admin for my slack app to do the following:

At a specific time I need to send a user a question and then based on their reply I will ask 1 more question.

So to summarize there will be 2 questions asked.
The first question will also include a interactive message that will allow the user to delay the question for 5 minutes or just stop the questioning flow.

Do I need to setup a **incoming webhook** or **Interactive components**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work with interactive components.

1. your bot sends the user a direct message with the question as interactive button or interactive menu (it will appear on the `Slackbot` channel of the user).
2. When the user answers by clicking on a button or menu item your app will receive his answer as request and can process it accordingly.

repeat above for the 2nd question

Note that your would need to implement a delay feature for your bot by your own. The Slack API does not offer any scheduling function.

Comment: I like interactive messages b/c they have a callback id.  Other than that delay button feature, my other questions are just open ended questions that are just text based (not a button or menu).  So I have to handle the responses as events then right? I subsribed to 'message.im' and I see messages users send to the botuser.  I wish I could use interactive messages for this but I can't right?

Comment: yes, you can subscribe to message.im events to get all messages posted by user in a direct message channel to your bot. that would work. Yes, you can not use interactive message for open ended text input, but you can use [Dialogs](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) for that. there you can present the user with one or multiple text boxes for free text entries.

Comment: so I would then suggest to send the user two buttons: one for delay, one to answer the question (which would open the Slack dialog with the actual questions)